# What use-cases for electron-store are not already covered and fulfilled by redux-persist?

Tags: redux, electron, redux-persist

With redux-persist ( https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist ) I managed to persist my first data within my Electron-React-Typescript-Webpack app without electron-store and without redux-persist-electron-storage .

So... I'm here to ask what are the use cases for electron-store and its redux-persist-adapter ( https://github.com/psperber/redux-persist-electron-storage ) that are not already covered and fulfilled by redux-persist?